# how to get path file selected in .netcore web api(IFromFile)

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi

my field is

```
    public IFormFileCollection FileNames { get; set; }
```

i get multiple file from postman (form-data) and post
in api-controller i get fields of send with postman

[image]

my problem here,i need to path of files, how i can get path of FromFile?

updated code :

```
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName.FileName, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        await fileName.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                        fileStream.Dispose();
                        var request = MyOperationOnFile(fileStream.Name);
                         ...
                    }
```

get this exception for second file(first file is ok):

```
"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'FileBufferingReadStream'."
```

if dont use .dispose() get this exception for first file :

```
Failed to send: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile, with error:The process cannot access the file 'porjectLocation\file' because it is being used by another process
```

Answer (score 4):

In fact, if you want to upload files, you do not need to know the original path of the files, but only need to `create the path you need to upload`.

The following is a case of uploading multiple files, please refer to it:

```
       [HttpPost("UploadFile")] 
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFileCollection files)
        {
            foreach (var fileName in files)
            {
                var filesPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Uploadfiles";
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(filesPath))//create path 
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(filesPath);
                }
                var path = Path.Combine(filesPath, Path.GetFileName(fileName.FileName));//the path to upload
                await fileName.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));

            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Worked as charm

Answer (score 0):

The form file that you received from the request are actually the stream in memory of the files, you will need to save it on the disk or on your database. Check the examples in the documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: i get multiple file,when copy files in project dir, i get this exception : "The process cannot access the file 'ProjectLocation\file' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code, but, make sure to dispose the stream after using it it might be causing the problem.

Comment: exception is : "Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'FileBufferingReadStream'."

Comment: you must not call `fileStream.Dispose();` if you are already using the `using` statement

Comment: if dont use .dispose() get this exception for first file :failed to send: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile, with error:The process cannot access the file 'porjectLocation\file' because it is being used by another process

Comment: Right, the problem that you need to figure out is this on about the file being used by another process. Are you trying to save the file in a different folder? or in the same folder of the original file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get the name of the first uploaded file, you can get the others in the same way :

```
IFormFileCollection Iffc = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
IFormFile formFile = null;

if (Iffc != null && Iffc.Count > 0)
{
     formFile = Iffc[0];  // first File
     if (formFile != null)
     {
         string name = formFile.FileName;
     }
}
```